# How to turn methods in another class as a method in a generic class

Tags: java, methods

I'm trying to create an Object called a 'measurement'. This measurement object has only one method, calculate(). (Could be an interface or class - not sure which is best).

I have many different measurements (hundreds, possibly more), and the way I'm trying to implement them is to have a class that contains all these measurements as static methods.

So I'm essentially trying to load a static method from a class into a Measurement object, where I can call measurement.calculate().

The way I'm starting to implement it, and the only way I can think of, is to use the Method class in Reflection, where each Measurement is instantiated with a Method (the static measurement method in a different class). The Measurement class' calculate() method would then invoke the method the respective object was instantiated with.

What's the best way to implement this?

Thank you!

Comment: I know I'm just supposed to answer and not question your motives but... dear god, why?

Comment: I have over 500 measurements. Most of them will be no longer than a single statement. I want to be able to modify/read the file that contains them easily. I'd prefer to keep them as method calls, but since that's not possible, I figured I'd make them all methods, as that's the only differentiation between them. Ultimately, I'd like to avoid making every single measurement, where many are slight variations of another, be its own class. I'm open to different methods, but I don't *think* it's too unreasonable to want to avoid making each a class. It seems unnecessarily painstaking for my needs.

Comment: I suppose an alternate method of doing this is to just contain all the methods within a class and to just utilize any methods within that class as measurements...

Comment: If you can give more detail about what a measurement is and what the code for a calculation would be for a few, we would be able to give you a better idea. Without deeper knowledge, it seems unlikely that you would have 500 items that are all completely unique. Also, with the help of an IDE, I don't think implementing 500 classes would be any less painful than implementing 500 methods. However, in the case of classes you get the benefit of an organized structure to your code.

Comment: These measurements are characterizations of financial data. Time-series, price and volume. I require characterizations/measurements taken at multiple time ranges. I suppose there may be a better way of grouping that I'm not aware of. One common measurement is the relative size (high-low compared to average of past 10 high-low distances) of a time period.

Answer (score 3):

This seems like you have decided on the way you want to do the task and have created more complicated issues along the way. You started out fine by suggesting that you would create an interface that all of your objects would implement. But grouping them all in one static class is where things start to fall apart.

A better organization would be to let each measurement class implement its calculate method. This way, when you are dealing with Foos, you don't have to go to one big class that has code that relates to Foos, Bars, Bizzes and Bazzes. You said you could have at least 100 classes, this will make your static class hard to work with in the first place. It is likely that you may not need that many implementations of calculate. You will be able to achieve this by building up a inheritance hierarchy which will further sub-divide and organize your code.

```
public interface Measurable<T> {
  T calculate();
}

public class Foo implements Measurable<Integer> {
  private int a;
  private int b;
  @Override
  Integer calculate() {
    return a + b;
  }
}

public class Foo implements Measurable<Double> {
  private double a;
  private double b;
  @Override
  Integer calculate() {
    return a / b;
  }
}
```

You have more information about what you are actually looking for, but that is a basic template that should provide a good example and show how you can make things flexible.

Comment: Also directed to @philonous, I want to avoid creating a class for each measurement implementation. I'd prefer for them not to be anymore than methods. I understand that this behavior typically would be implemented by wrapping each inside its own class, but this is what I was hoping to avoid for the sake of reducing text.

Comment: Another alternative I can think of is to forget about the Measurement class, and just manage the measurements as any method within the class all the measurement methods are defined in.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated your problem, you should implement the "measurement object" as an interface. It has only one method and this method should be implemented by all the single specific "measurement-objects". Your approach looks more like a [God class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_class) augmented with introspective code – just to imitate the behavior which is achieved more easily by using [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming).

So to be a bit more concrete:

```
public interface Measurable {
    public void calculate();
}
```

And the single measurement strategies would then be implemented as follows:

```
public class MeasurementA implements Measurable {

    @Override
    public void calculate() {
        System.out.println("I am doing a very cool measurement.");
    }

}
```

This could then be used in the following manner:

```
public class Controller {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Measurable> measurables = new ArrayList<Measurable>();
        measurables.add(new MeasurementA());
        measurables.add(new MeasurementB());

        for (Measurable measurement : measurables) {
            measurement.calculate();
        }
}
```